# Plotting a "ragged array" - a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatterplot

I have a list of numeric vectors, not necessarily all the same length.

I'd like to get a plot where each vector in the list is plotted vertically above a label for that vector on the x-axis.

Is there an "automatic way" to do that in R?

Here's an example set of data:

```
 yl = structure(list(
           A = c(4.232886, 3.338263, 1.765557, 1.438516), 
           B = c(3.046518, 4.500074, 1.508675, 3.226517, 5.982371, 1.519653), 
           C = c(5.788882, 7.644319)
         ), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"))
```

In this case I'd like labels A, B and C on the x-axis, and the corresponding data values plotted vertically parallel to the y-axis.

Comment: I've edited your question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. See `?stack` and `?stripchart`

```
 yls = stack(yl)  # stacks up the vectors, using names of each as the factor labels
 stripchart(values~ind,yls,pch=1,vertical=TRUE)  # plot the data vertically
```

[image]

You might like to try these and see what they do:

```
 plot(values~ind,yls)
 plot(yls)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's exactly what I was looking for! Perfect.
Next time I will provide a reproducible example.